# Adding # Format to Values

Tags: vba, excel, number-formatting

I have a simple form where I have a user inputting certain data. With that data, I need some values calculated and I also need the values to come up as either currency or percentage.

The code is:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    Dim emptyRow As Long
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim A As Long
    Dim B As Long
    Dim C As Long
    Dim D As Long
    Dim E As Long
    Dim Answer As Long
    Dim Answer2 As Long
    Dim Answer3 As Long

    If Me.txtNoTotalAff.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the Total Number of Affiliates", vbExclamation, "ROI"
        Me.txtNoTotalAff.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Me.lstClientName.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter Client Name", vbExclamation, "ROI"
        Me.lstClientName.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Determine Empty Row
    emptyRow = Sheets("ROI").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    A = CLng(txtNoTotalAff.Value)
    B = CLng(txtActiveAff.Value)
    C = CLng(txtAvgTraffic.Value)
    D = CLng(txtConvRate.Value)
    E = CLng(txtAOV.Value)

    Answer = A * B
    Answer2 = Answer * C
    Answer3 = (Answer2 * D) * E

    'Transfer Information
    Sheets("ROI").Cells(emptyRow, 1) = lstClientName.Value     'Col "A"
    Sheets("ROI").Cells(emptyRow, 2) = txtNoTotalAff.Value     'Col "B"
    Sheets("ROI").Cells(emptyRow, 3) = txtActiveAff.Value      'Col "C"
    Sheets("ROI").Cells(emptyRow, 4) = Answer                 'Col "D"
    Sheets("ROI").Cells(emptyRow, 5) = txtAvgTraffic.Value     'Col "E"
    Sheets("ROI").Cells(emptyRow, 6) = Answer2                'Col "F"
    Sheets("ROI").Cells(emptyRow, 7) = txtConvRate.Value      'Col "G"
    Sheets("ROI").Cells(emptyRow, 8) = txtAOV.Value            'Col "H"
    Sheets("ROI").Cells(emptyRow, 9) = Answer3                'Col "I"
    Sheets("ROI").Cells(emptyRow, 10) = txtAffName.Value      'Col "J"

    'Clear the Form
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
            ctl.Value = ""
        ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
            ctl.Value = False
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub
```

I need the `txtNoTotalAff.Value`, `AvgTraffic.Value`, `Answer` & `Answer2` to come up as number. I need the `txtActiveAff.Value` and `txtConvRate.Value` to be %. The `txtAOV.value` and `Answer 3` should be currency.

I tried adding in after each sheets.("ROI") a `.NumberFormat= "Percentage"` but that did not work.
I also am not getting a correct answer when I use the form as the calculated fields are coming up as 0. Any ideas?

Comment: Try declaring your variables as Double instead of Long. Also try formatting the cells that you are placing values into. For example, this would format for currency for any amount of dollars up to 9.9 Billion: 
     Sheets("ROI").Cells(emptyRow, col).NumberFormat = "$#,###,###,##0.00"

Comment: I'll try this and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up using in case it ever helps someone else!

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long
Dim ctl As Control
Dim A, B, C, D, E, Answer, Answer2, Answer3 As Double


If Me.txtNoTotalAff.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please enter the Total Number of Affiliates", vbExclamation, "ROI"
    Me.txtNoTotalAff.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
If Me.lstClientName.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please enter Client Name", vbExclamation, "ROI"
    Me.lstClientName.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
'Determine Empty Row
emptyRow = Sheets("ROI").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
A = CDbl(txtNoTotalAff.Value)
B = CDbl(txtActiveAff.Value)
C = CDbl(txtAvgTraffic.Value)
D = CDbl(txtConvRate.Value)
E = CDbl(txtAOV.Value)

Answer = A * B
Answer2 = Answer * C
Answer3 = (Answer2 * D) * E

   'Transfer Information
    With Sheets("ROI")
    .Cells(emptyRow, 2).NumberFormat = "0"
    .Cells(emptyRow, 3).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    .Cells(emptyRow, 4).NumberFormat = "0"
    .Cells(emptyRow, 5).NumberFormat = "0"
    .Cells(emptyRow, 6).NumberFormat = "0"
    .Cells(emptyRow, 7).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    .Cells(emptyRow, 8).NumberFormat = "$#"
    .Cells(emptyRow, 9).NumberFormat = "$#"
    .Cells(emptyRow, 1) = lstClientName.Value     'Col "A"
    .Cells(emptyRow, 2) = txtNoTotalAff.Value   'Col "B"
    .Cells(emptyRow, 3) = txtActiveAff.Value   'Col "C"
    .Cells(emptyRow, 4) = Answer               'Col "D"
    .Cells(emptyRow, 5) = txtAvgTraffic.Value   'Col "E"
    .Cells(emptyRow, 6) = Answer2              'Col "F"
    .Cells(emptyRow, 7) = txtConvRate.Value    'Col "G"
    .Cells(emptyRow, 8) = txtAOV.Value         'Col "H"
    .Cells(emptyRow, 9) = Answer3              'Col "I"
    .Cells(emptyRow, 10) = txtAffName.Value      'Col "J"

MsgBox "Total Sales: $" & Answer3, vbExclamation, "The Affiliate will need to          generate!"

End With


'Clear the Form
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
    ctl.Value = ""
    ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
    ctl.Value = False
    End If
Next ctl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    Dim emptyRow As Long
    Dim ctl As Control
    'Do not convert to long type as in calculation will be long also, 
    'e.g. Clng(2.3)*Clng(3.6) result will be 8 instead of 8.28,
    'for calculation use decimal or single or double depending on required accuracy 
    'to get decimal do not specify data type
    'data type is variant for the variables (A, B, C, D, E, Answer,Answer2, Answer3)
    'but when you assign data like Cdec(value), variables will be converted to decimal
    Dim A, B, C, D, E, Answer, Answer2, Answer3
    If Me.txtNoTotalAff.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the Total Number of Affiliates", vbExclamation, "ROI"
        Me.txtNoTotalAff.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Me.lstClientName.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter Client Name", vbExclamation, "ROI"
        Me.lstClientName.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Determine Empty Row
    emptyRow = Sheets("ROI").Range("A" & Rows.Count).END(xlUp).Row + 1
    A = CDec(txtNoTotalAff.Value) 'convert to decimal, not to long
    B = CDec(txtActiveAff.Value) 'convert to decimal, not to long
    C = CDec(txtAvgTraffic.Value) 'convert to decimal, not to long
    D = CDec(txtConvRate.Value) 'convert to decimal, not to long
    E = CDec(txtAOV.Value)
    Answer = A * B: Answer2 = Answer * C: Answer3 = (Answer2 * D) * E
    'Transfer Information
    With Sheets("ROI")
        'Use this here, depending on which format of the cell you need
        '.Cells(Row, Column).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        '.Cells(Row, Column).NumberFormat = "[$$-409]#,##0.00"
        .Cells(emptyRow, 1) = lstClientName.Value    'Col "A"
        .Cells(emptyRow, 2) = txtNoTotalAff.Value    'Col "B"
        .Cells(emptyRow, 3) = txtActiveAff.Value     'Col "C"
        .Cells(emptyRow, 4) = Answer                 'Col "D"
        .Cells(emptyRow, 5) = txtAvgTraffic.Value    'Col "E"
        .Cells(emptyRow, 6) = Answer2                'Col "F"
        .Cells(emptyRow, 7) = txtConvRate.Value      'Col "G"
        .Cells(emptyRow, 8) = txtAOV.Value           'Col "H"
        .Cells(emptyRow, 9) = Answer3                'Col "I"
        .Cells(emptyRow, 10) = txtAffName.Value      'Col "J"
    End With
    'Clear the Form
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
            ctl.Value = ""
        ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
            ctl.Value = False
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub
```

Comment: But some of the numbers cannot be a decimal. For instance txtNoTotalAffs.Value, txtAvgTraffic.Value can only be whole numbers. Would I still leave it as CDec?

Comment: @BethanyMinor yes, "whole number" will be a "whole number", does not metter will it be long or integer or single or double or decimal. but if you will use in calculation something like clng(15.5) it will return 16 as long type, and you will not receive (in your case multiply) value with floating point, especially with percentage and currency where you want to add #format

Comment: Thanks Vasily. I ended up using Double and CDbl instead of CDec because I kept getting an error when I tried to use the others, but this did the trick.